# "get a sibbling" problem

Tags: jquery, html

i am struggling with the following :

I am loading news messages from a other html page in my site :

on first html page i have :

```
<div class="post_box">
      <div class="newsexcerpt1"></div>
</div>
<div class="post_box">
      <div class="newsexcerpt2"></div>
</div>
```

on my second page(news1.html) i have :

```
<div id="nieuws">
  <div class="news">
        <div class="newsexcerpt">bla die bla die bla </div>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
       <div class="newsexcerpt">bla die bla die bla </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I try to get it working with :

```
$('.newsexcerpt1').load('news1.html .newsexcerpt:first');
$('.newsexcerpt2').load('news1.html .newsexcerpt').next('news1.html .newsexcerpt:first');
```

The first line of $ is running smoothly , but get the second is the big problem

how can i get the next .newsexcerpt ?

is there someone who can help me ?

Thnx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just want a different selector here.  To get the "nth" match of a selector, use the [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/),  like this:

```
$('.newsexcerpt1').load('news1.html .newsexcerpt:first');
$('.newsexcerpt2').load('news1.html .newsexcerpt:eq(1)');
```